# JQuery stops working with Cordova

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a weird problem, hoping someone can help out. I'm trying to create a really simple app with Cordova just to explore its features and set up a base 'shell' application from which I can use as a start point for future work rather than starting from scratch.

A summary of some frameworks I have implemented:

- Cordova 4.2.0
- JQuery 1.11.2
- JQuery Mobile 1.4.5

So the basic problem is that when I load a page in the app everything works ok. But after I navigate away to another page JQuery stops working. I have a basic landing page which allows a user to click a button and from the menu choose to get a photo from the gallery or camera and display on screen. This works fine.

I then use JQuery Mobile Panel widget with a list of links as my navigation. After clicking one and going to another page (e.g. about.html), the JQuery on any other page doesn't work. When navigating to about.html the main text should change to "Changed Hello World" based on the script at the bottom of that page but it remains as "Hello World".

When I test this in a web browser everything works ok, but on the device I get nothing. Swapping pages around does nothing either, for example loading About page first works, but then navigating to Photo breaks that functionality.

I have a feeling it has something to do with JQuery Mobile and its Ajax navigation and page loading etc but I can't prove it. Thought it might have something to do with JQuery conflicts too so I've played around with the order of imports and $.noConflict but it seemed to make things worse. Anyone else got these frameworks to play nicely together?

Here is my example:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/simple-orange.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />

 <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
   
        <div data-role="header" data-icon="bars" >
         <a class="ui-nodisc-icon" data-iconpos="notext" href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars"></a>
            <h1>My Title</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
 
        <div data-role="content">
           <h2 id="hea">Upload Photo</h2>
   <form>
    <label for="file">Choose a photo:</label>
    <a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-camera ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Add photo</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="b"><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Add from</li>
    <li data-icon="false"><a id="camera-link" href="#">Camera</a></li>
    <li data-icon="false"><a id="gallery-link" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   </form>
   <img id="photo-thumb" />
        </div><!-- /content -->
 
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>My Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
   <div data-role="panel" id="nav-panel" >
    <ul data-role="listview">
       <li data-icon="false"><a href="./form.html">Form</a></li>
       <li data-icon="false"><a href="./photo.html">Photo</a></li>
       <li data-icon="false"><a href="./about.html">About</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
    </div><!-- /page -->
    <script>
 
  $("#hea").html('New Upload Photo');
  $("#camera-link").click(function(e){
   console.log('click called');
   console.log('prevented default');
   takePhoto();
  });
  $("#gallery-link").click(function(e){
   selectPhoto();
  }); 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```js
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

var permanentStorage = window.localStorage;
var tempStorage = window.sessionStorage;



function showToken() {
 var p = document.getElementById('token');
 p.innerHTML = tempStorage.getItem('token');
}

function storeToken() {
 permanentStorage.setItem('deviceid', "abc123");
 tempStorage.setItem('token', "DLJKSD#$()*#@$HKS");
 showToken();
}

function takePhoto() {
 console.log('taking photo');
 navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
  quality : 50,
  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
 });
}

function selectPhoto() {
 navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
  quality : 50,
  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
 });
}

function onSuccess(imageData) {
 var image = $('#photo-thumb');
 image.attr('src', "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
}

function onFail(message) {
 alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

**about.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/simple-orange.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />

 <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

<title>About</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div data-role="page">

  <div data-role="header" data-icon="bars">
   <a class="ui-nodisc-icon" data-iconpos="notext" href="#nav-panel"
    data-icon="bars"></a>
   <h1>About</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /header -->

  <div data-role="content">
   <h1 id="myhead">Hello world</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /content -->

  <div data-role="panel" id="nav-panel" >
    <ul data-role="listview">
       <li data-icon="false"><a href="./form.html">Form</a></li>
       <li data-icon="false"><a href="./photo.html">Photo</a></li>
       <li data-icon="false"><a href="./about.html">About</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script>
  $("#myhead").html('Changed Hello World');
 </script>
 <!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is a prime example of why someone would use a single page design pattern for Cordova applications. One should really not be reloading pages and re-instantiating `cordova.js` and various other `JS` libs. With a single page design pattern every resource is only loaded once and gives a more native experience to the end user.

Comment: Sounds like you have experience here @dawson-louden, could you recommend a framework that is useful here? Are you thinking something like Angular JS?

Comment: I use vanilla JS/CSS to show/hide different 'page' views from one html file, and I have also used `Handlebars.js` for templating. If you want a full featured framework, check out `Ionic` http://www.ionicframework.com its based on angular and made specifically for building Cordova applications.